# Sequence of harmonic measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, brownian-motion, potential-theory

There is a well-known result stating that if $\mu_{n}$ is a sequence of uniformly bounded measures on a compact set $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, then there is a subsequence $\mu_{n_{j}}$ that converges weakly to some measure $\mu$ on $E$. Now, suppose $D$ is a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ with $m>1$ and $y$ a point on the boundary $\partial D$ of $D$. Take a sequence $x_{n}$ in $D$ that converges to $y$ and consider the sequence $\omega(x_{n},D)$ (harmonic measure of $D$ at $x_{n}$. This sequence has a subsequence that converges weakly to some $\mu$ on $\partial D$. My question is: is $\mu$ known? What do we know about it?

Comment: Usually, this is the Dirac measure at $y$. (Unless $y$ is irregular for the Dirichlet problem.)

Comment: Thanks. Now suppose that for some continuous function $f$ on $\partial D$, there is  a subset $A$ of $\partial D$ that does NOT contain $y$ and $$\int_{\partial D}fd\omega(x_{n},D)=\int_{A}fd\omega(x_{n},D).$$ Can $y$ be steel a regular point and the subsequence converge to $f(y)$?!

Comment: Sorry, I do not get your comment. Set $f = 0$ on $\partial D$ (or at least on $(\partial D) \setminus A$). Your condition is then obviously satisfied, but why would it imply anything about regularity of a boundary point $y$?

Comment: Suppose for instance that $A$ is relatively close in $\partial D$. Then the above integral of the right equals $$\int_{\partial D}\chi_{A}fd\omega(x_{n},D)\to\chi_{A}(y)f(y)=0$$ for all continuous function $f$, because $y$ doesn't belong to $A$.

Comment: Your last comment states the following: if $A$ is a closed subset of $\partial D$ and $y \in (\partial D) \setminus A$, then the solution of the Dirichlet problem with boundary data $\chi_A f$ converges to zero at $y$. This statement is equivalent to $y$ being regular for the Dirichlet problem in $D$. And what is the question?

Comment: But if $f=1$ every where this is a contradiction. The limit should not be equal to zero.

Comment: Sorry, where is the contradiction? If $f = 1$, the harmonic function with boundary values $f \chi_A = \chi_A$ converges to zero at every regular boundary point of $D$ which does not belong to $A$ (and to one at every regular boundary point in the relative interior of $A$). Why would the limit not be zero?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I think you are right.